# .htaccess - write a clean URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to write a clean URL for my application. I searched and have written following, but it does not work and gives "Server not found error".

I have URL like this

```
 http://localhost/projectFolder/user_folders/userName/testSite2/
```

and I want it to be -

```
  http://testSite2.mySystemDomain.com/
```

I have tried as follows, but it fails.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/user_folders/userName/testSite2/(.*) http://testSite2.mySystemDomain.com/$1
```

**EDIT**

There will be number of sites like testSite2. I need to write the URL for each such site.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in .htaccess in folder projectFolder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user_folders/(.*)/(.*) http://$1.mySystemDomain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: There will be number of sites like testSite2. I need to write the URL for each such site.

Comment: Made changes accordingly. Let me know if you have more conditions, I ll change the query accordingly.

Comment: I added the above code to htacess in project folder, but it gives "server not found" error. Actually, I had envisioned that, for each site I'll be creating an htaccess file. Can you provide me some link where I can understand the concepts. Anyways thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Do you really have site called "testSite2.mySystemDomain.com"?. Server not found error comes when you have no server with above name?. Documents is http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, I have a folder testSite2 at http://localhost/projectFolder/user_folders/ and it contains all the files for the site

Comment: ok. Thats not how it works. you need to have subdomain called testSite2.mySystemDomain.com.

Comment: What should I do ? Please guide.

Comment: 1. Add a dns entry with wildcard subdomain *.mySystemDomain.com to the ip of your site. 2. you need to handle it in virtual host of your apache, config will be ServerName www.mySystemDomain.com ServerAlias *.mySystemDomain.com